# Parse User automatically logged out randomly on some app restarts

Tags: parse-platform, pfuser

I've been hearing reports from some people using my app that they're being randomly logged out of their PFUser account (`[PFUser currentUser] == nil`). Up until a few weeks ago, I've always found that once a user is logged in, they stay logged in indefinitely on the same device, so I don't know where to begin with what's causing the logouts.

Not many details, unfortunately, but I have found that the problem is only confirmed with iOS users so far. Also, some iOS users have been getting errors with code 209 for invalid session token, but those users aren't being automatically logged out.

Anyone have any pointers on where I should be looking for problems? Thanks!

Comment: On the Parse app that I have been working on, it has both Android and iOS users, and we are experiencing this same issue.  Users will be randomly logged out after a couple days of continuous use of the app.  We are using PFUser.currentUser to check for login status.

Comment: @DivideByZer0 yeah, that's how I've been checking as well. Still haven't found a reason for the problem. I guess I should raise it as an issue in the Git repository.

Comment: Sure, let me know if you have so I can follow the thread!